# Call aspx, html pages from another aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one aspx page where I want to display contents of another aspx or html page based on the sessions. Code behind logic will fetch the file from particular location based on the session. I do not want to use frames, iframes because I have to make sure of cross browser compatibility. Is there any other way to achieve this?

User control may be a solution for this. I wanted to know more alternate approach.

Below is my code:

I don't have anything in aspx except the references to the external js file.

Code behind:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _getMainMenu();

        }
protected string _getMainMenu()
{
  string HomePageMenu = string.Empty;
 string homeExist = Server.MapPath("../homepages/" + Session["ACCOUNT"].ToString() + "/HomePage.htm");
                if (File.Exists(homeExist ))
                {
                    HomePageMenu = "../homepages/" + Session["ACCOUNT"].ToString() + "/HomePage.htm";
                }
                else
                {
                    HomePageMenu = "../homepages/NewMenu.html";
                }
return HomePageMenu ;
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401304/load-and-render-a-aspx-file-in-a-server-control

Comment: You could use an <iframe> pointing to the other page, but I can't even start to describe how awful it would be.

Comment: If you want to show similar content on two different pages, a user control is certainly one way to do that.  I think you might have more success in getting an answer if you actually posted some code of something you tried.

Comment: Convert your HomePage.htm into .ascx controls.

Comment: @IhorDeyneka: If I convert .htm to .ascx do I need to register in my aspx like other user controls? In some occasion I may need to render content of another aspx file. What should do in that case? Please suggest.

Comment: How is an iframe going to diminish cross browser compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe something like [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is something that may be helpful.  This will asynchronously retrieve content and place it into a control of your choice, and not necessarily an iframe of course.  This is called from the client, but you can have your server side logic/session state determine the content returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the way you manage your content in generally.
In your case, your aspx-page is your content. And if you want to show contant b in contant a, you will have to show an aspx-page inside another aspx-page.

Change the point of view: your aspx-page should only be your content-holder. Extract your content to an ascx-usercontrol or store it in a database.

Then you are able to fetch the content whereever you need them.

Showing an aspx-page inside another is a very bad solution.

But if it's not possible to change the way your content is stored: I would prefere an iframe.